# NO_CALLBACK is being called when should not

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a scrapy spider. In a callback method that yields requests with NO_CALLBACK set in callback

A parse callback yields new requets, with callback arg set to NO_CALLBACK, which indicates scrapy to don't call callback at all, but it's calling it and raising this error:
`RuntimeError: The NO_CALLBACK callback has been called. This is a special callback value intended for requests whose callback is never meant to be called.`

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from scrapy.http.request import NO_CALLBACK


class AppsSpider(Spider):
    name = "Apps"
    allowed_domains = ['steampowered.com', 'steamstatic.com']
    start_urls = ['https://store.steampowered.com/app/20']

    def parse(self, response: TextResponse):
        # preview media
        preview_section = response.css('#game_highlights')
        main_image_selector = '.game_header_image_full::attr("src")'
        preview_img_selector = '.highlight_screenshot a::attr("href")'
        preview_videos_selector = '.highlight_movie::attr("data-mp4-hd-source")'
        links = preview_section.css(
            ', '.join([main_image_selector, preview_img_selector, preview_videos_selector])).getall()

        # description section media
        description_section = response.css('#aboutThisGame')
        description_img_gif_selector = 'img::attr("src")'
        links += description_section.css(description_img_gif_selector).getall()

        yield from response.follow_all(links, callback=NO_CALLBACK)
```

Tried to solve it removing the `errback callback, cb_kwargs, meta, and dont_filter=True`. None of it worked.

The doc says:

> When assigned to the callback parameter of Request, it indicates that the request is not meant to have a spider callback at all.

Edit:
Edited to be mre, you can run it using scrapy runspider nameofscript.py

Here's the traceback:

```
2023-04-02 21:12:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/20/0000000164.1920x1080.jpg?t=1579634708> (referer: https://store.steampowered.com/app/20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leiver\miniconda3\envs\steam-scraping\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\leiver\miniconda3\envs\steam-scraping\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 40, in NO_CALLBACK
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: The NO_CALLBACK callback has been called. This is a special callback value intended for requests whose callback is never meant to be called.
```

Comment: please provide a proper [mre]

Comment: @Alexander mre done, keep getting the error

Comment: So what is the issue?  That is what it is supposed to do...  What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Is not it supposed to indicate to download the request but not to be processed in a callback, e.g when sending a request just to get a cookie, not processing the response. If leave callback empty it will call parse by default, for that is NO_CALLBACK. PLease correct me if am misunderstanding the doc @Alexander

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: I think so. It's intended to be a kinda flag to be captured in middlewares. I misunderstood the doc, but now I get it. Anyway, is there a simple way to indicate scrapy not  to process the response for specific requests?

Comment: A simple way?  Depends on what you might consider simple.  Writing a custom middleware that recognizes the NO_CALLBACK callback isn't that complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing magic about the `NO_CALLBACK`.  When you yield a request to the scrapy engine, by default it will always attempt to process the response using the default callback or the one specified using the callback parameter, this is true even when the callback is `NO_CALLBACK`. What `NO_CALLBACK` is supposed to do is act as a flag of sorts so that you can write custom middleware that listens for it, and treats it differently than standard scrapy requests.

If we look at the source code for the `scrapy.http.requests.NO_CALLBACK` you see:

```
def NO_CALLBACK(*args, **kwargs):
    """When assigned to the ``callback`` parameter of
    :class:`~scrapy.http.Request`, it indicates that the request is not meant
    to have a spider callback at all.
    For example:
    .. code-block:: python
       Request("https://example.com", callback=NO_CALLBACK)
    This value should be used by :ref:`components <topics-components>` that
    create and handle their own requests, e.g. through
    :meth:`scrapy.core.engine.ExecutionEngine.download`, so that downloader
    middlewares handling such requests can treat them differently from requests
    intended for the :meth:`~scrapy.Spider.parse` callback.
    """
    raise RuntimeError(
        "The NO_CALLBACK callback has been called. This is a special callback "
        "value intended for requests whose callback is never meant to be "
        "called."
    )
```

And if you search in the documentation the only example that can be found that uses the class never actually yields the request, and instead calls the scrapy engine directly.

[docs example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=NO_CALLBACK#take-screenshot-of-item)

```
request = scrapy.Request(screenshot_url, callback=NO_CALLBACK)
response = await maybe_deferred_to_future(
            spider.crawler.engine.download(request, spider)
        )
```